# I have a list of datatable, how can I copy that list into single datatable in c#

Tags: c#

```
public DataTable LoadPaymentsList()
{
   List< DataTable > lstDts = new List< DataTable >();
   // Copy into  dt
   Datatable dt=new Datatable();
   return dt;
}
```

Comment: Are those tables contains same columns? how that  `lstDts` is populated?

Comment: yes, all the column names are same.For populating lstDts I have done this code already

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a better way than simple `Row`- and `Column`-Adding:

```
DataTable mergedTable = new DataTable();
List<DataTable> tableCollection = new List<DataTable>();
/*---------------------------------*/

bool columnsAdded = false;
foreach (DataTable table in tableCollection)
{
    if (!columnsAdded)
    {
        foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
        {
            mergedTable.Columns.Add(column);
        }
        columnsAdded = true;
    }
    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        mergedTable.Rows.Add(row);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to have a look into merging tables . Check this for further info on dataTable Merging, http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0c1bb2/merging-multiple-datatables-into-single-datatable-using-asp/

```
//merging first data table into second data table  
         dt2.Merge(dt);  
         dt2.AcceptChanges();
```